# How do I solve this Laplace equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

I'm stuck with the following problem:

> Suppose we have an inﬁnitely long box whose cross-section has a rectangular shape of dimensions 2×3. Take the four last digits of your student ID number as a set of four integers, and assign them as the values of the electrostatic potential on the four surfaces. If your 4 integers contain no zeros, set one of them as zero. On the other hand, if the 4 numbers contain more than one zeros, replace them with nonzero values except for only one of those. In short, your boundary surfaces should have three non-zero potentials and one grounded. Find the electrostatic potential inside the box. (Hint: Use the method of Section 3.1 in Chapter 3.)

The textbook is Griffits's "*Introduction to Electrodynamics*" 4th ed. (The problem is not from the textbook, though). The problem asks me to use $4$ numbers from my student ID number. For my case, they are 0, 2, 2, 3. I know I need to solve the Lapace equation
$$ \frac{\partial^2 \Phi} {\partial x^2} + \frac {\partial^2 \Phi} {\partial y^2} = 0$$
with the following boundary conditions:
$$\Phi = 0 \ \text{if} \ y = 0\text{,}\tag{1}$$
$$\Phi = 3 \ \text{if} \ y = 3\text{,}\tag{2}$$
$$\Phi = 2 \ \text{if} \ x = 0\text{,}\tag{3}$$
$$\Phi = 2 \ \text{if} \ x = 2\text{.}\tag{4}$$
I tried using separation of variables method. So I have to solve
$$\frac {d^2 X} {dx^2} = aX, \ \frac {d^2 Y} {dy^2} = -aY\text{.}$$
I only tried solving the case $a>0$. In that case, $X = Ae^{\sqrt a x} + Be^{-\sqrt a x}$ and $Y = C\sin \sqrt a y + D\cos \sqrt a y$. Using the boundary condition (1), I see that $D=0$. But I can't go any further.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you want is *not* going to be separable, so if you want to use separation of variables, the best that you can hope for is to find your solution as a superposition of separable individual solutions.

If you want to do that, then you're better off separating the problem into, say, $$\Phi(0,y) = \Phi(a,y) = \Phi(x,0) = 0$$ (for box dimensions $a$ and $b$) and $\Phi(x,b) = \Phi_0$, and then taking the core separable solution,
$$
\Phi_n\mathopen{}(x,y)\mathclose{} = \sin(n\pi \,x/a) \sinh(n\pi \,y/a),
$$
and building up your solution $\Phi(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n \Phi_n\mathopen{}(x,y)\mathclose{}$ as a superposition of the separable solutions by using a suitable series decomposition of the boundary condition.

Everything else, you've got to do yourself.

---

(While you're there, though - it's important to note that the Fourier series that comes out of this has some severe convergence problems (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) for where to get started on the details), involving a substantial degree of subtlety. This is not an artifact, and the ill-behaviour is already there in the problem you've set, since you've got a discontinuous change in the potential at the boundary, which cannot be instantiated in physical scenarios, and would require infinite electric fields if you did.)

Comment: Thanks! But that doesn't suit the boundary conditions. For instance, $\Phi(0, y)$ should be $2$ rather than $0$.

Comment: @zxcv It should be obvious that you need to repeat this four times (for your specific case, three), rotating the orientation of the core separable solution, and then add the solutions.